# Encontrar valores en un array con Input

Tags: javascript, html

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de utilizar un input tipo text para encontrar valores dentro de un array.

Por ejemplo si tengo un array de 10 personas, pero quiero usar un input para localizar a x persona, hacer que sus datos aparezcan en un label,etc.

Como si utilizara un prompt, si ingrese el Código correcto aparezca su info, pero en este caso en un input.
como este ejemplo:

```js
var user = new Array();
  var cod = prompt("Ingrese codigo =");
   user = new Array();
     user['C04'] = 'Jose' + ' Localidad 1' + ' +1 2039 03290' + ' hoka@gmail.com';
     user['C05'] = 'Mario' + ' Localidad 2' + ' +1 3938 92839' + ' qwerty@hotmail.com';

  document.write(user[cod]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como remplazar el `prompt` por `input`

```js
var user = new Array();
user['C04'] = 'Jose' + ' Localidad 1' + ' +1 2039 03290' + ' hoka@gmail.com';
user['C05'] = 'Mario' + ' Localidad 2' + ' +1 3938 92839' + ' qwerty@hotmail.com';

var elm = document.getElementById("codigo"),
 frame = document.getElementById("frame");
elm.addEventListener("change", function() {
 frame.innerHTML = user[this.value];
});
```

```html
Ingrese Codigo = <input id="codigo">
<div id="frame"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentarlo con un evento **keyup** y ver el resultado en tiempo real

```js
var user = new Array();
user['c04'] = 'Jose' + ' Localidad 1' + ' +1 2039 03290' + ' hoka@gmail.com';
user['c05'] = 'Mario' + ' Localidad 2' + ' +1 3938 92839' + ' qwerty@hotmail.com';

var text = document.getElementById("codigo")
var usuario = document.getElementById("usuario");

text.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
 usuario.innerHTML = user[this.value.toLowerCase()];
 
 if(usuario.innerHTML === "undefined"){
  usuario.innerHTML = "no existen registros";
 }
 
});
```

```html
Ingrese Codigo = <input type="text" id="codigo" placeholder="Ingresa el codigo">
<br>
<div id="usuario"></div>
```

algo que podría ayudar al criterio de búsqueda es que las letras de los códigos de las personas estén en minúsculas, así cuando el usuario ingrese el código, puedes usar el `toLowerCase()` y la comparación es mas fácil.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ha sido de utilidad